# Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: error when making pagination in php

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-2'

This happens when I delete everything from the table in php file which has the pagination. If I delete code for pagination, then its okay. But I need to have pagination, so someone please help.

This is my code:

```
<?php 
      $title = "Questions"; 
      require_once("header.php"); 
      require_once("db.php");

      $page= (empty($_GET['page'])) ? 1 : (int) $_GET['page'];
      $numberPerPage = 2;
      $query="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM questions";
      $result= $conn->query($query);

      if($result){
          $polje = $result->fetch_row();
          $total_questions = $polje[0];
      }else{
          echo 'Error';
      }

         $pageNumber= ceil($total_questions/$numberPerPage);
         if ($page < 1) $page = 1;
         else if ($page > $pageNumber-1) $page = $pageNumber;
         $odmak = $numberPerPage*($page -1);

          $query="SELECT*FROM questions ORDER BY question DESC LIMIT $numberPerPage OFFSET $odmak";
          $sql = $conn->query($query, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);

          if($sql){
               while ($row=$sql->fetch_assoc()){
                    echo"
                <a class='link' href='detalji_upit.php?detalji=$row[id]'>
                    <div class='card' style='width: 100%;'>
                        <div class='upiti_box'>
                            <h4><b>" . $user . "</b></h4> 
                            <p class='question'> " . $row['question'] . "</p>
                            <h4 class='answer'> answer: " . $row['answer'] . "</b></h4></br>
                            <a href='uredi_upit.php?edit=$row[id]' class='btn-edit'><i class='icon-reply'></i> Odgovori</a></br></th></br>
                            <a href='svi_upiti.php?obrisi=$row[id]' onclick=\"javascript: return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');\" class='btn-delete'><i class='icon-trash'></i> </a></br></br>";
                        echo "</div>
                    </div></br>
                </a>";
           }else{
               echo "<div style='padding: 10px'>
               <div class='alert alert-warning animate__animated animate__backInLeft'>Questions are empty!</div>
                </div>";
            }
            $conn->close();

    if ($pageNumber>1) {
        echo "<div style='clear: left; margin-top:50px;'>";
        echo "<ul class='pagination pagination-sm'>";
    
        if($page>1) {
            echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='svi_upiti.php?stranica=" . ($stranica-1) . "'>
            &laquo Prethodna </a></li>";
        }
        for($i=1;$i<=$pageNumber; $i++){
            if ($i==$stranica) echo "<li class='page-item active'><span class='page-link'> $i </span></li>";
            else echo "<li class='page-item class='page-link'><a class='page-link' href='svi_upiti.php?stranica=$i'> $i </a></li>";
        }
        if ($page<$pageNumber){
            echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='svi_upiti.php?stranica=" . ($stranica+1) . "'>
            Sljedeća &raquo </a></li>";
        }
            echo"</ul></div>";
     }
```

Comment: Echo out your query. It sounds like you're using -2 for the offset or limit. Once you find which one is -2, you can go about fixing it.

Comment: Why are you even proceeding with this, when $total_questions is 0? Make a condition that checks for that and outputs a "no records to show" message then, and only otherwise proceeds with querying the data and creating the pagination.